# sqlite: Import file that can not be stored in memory

Tags: database, sqlite, csv, import, large-files

I have a 72 Gb file that I would like to place in a database, such that I can group by. Is there a way to place this in a **sqlite** database?

I have tried the following:

```
.mode csv
.separator ;
.import c:/location/of/file/file.csv tablename
```

During the import I get an **out of memory** error.

Is it possible to use sqlite for such large files (of one only has 32 Gb memory), or do I have to use another type of databases?

Answer (score 0):

Before import, try the following statement :

```
PRAGMA temp_store = 1;
PRAGMA temp_store_directory = 'directory-name';
```

temp_store = 1 is for storing temp data in a file 
In temp_store_directory , specify the path of your temp directory e.g : C:/sqlitetemp

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out later today, and let you know if it worked :)

Comment: It still ran out of memory :(